# Does outside air conditioning compressor fan run all the time?

Tags: electrical, hvac

Had some electrical issues with an air conditioner and after I rewired it, I noticed that the fan was stopping every 30 seconds or so.  Is this fan supposed to shut off when unit is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you still have some rewiring left to do, the fan shouldn't stop while the compressor is on. If the fan isn't on, your air conditioner won't be able to dissipate all of the heat that is generated by the compressor, making the compressor less effective ( or not at all effective ).

Comment: You are right.  I had the fan/compressor wires flipped at the capacitor.